# Replacing text between two HTML Comments

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I am new to the world of `sed`/`awk` and regex in general and have been studying their usage, but have been floundering trying to meet my need:

I have an `htm` page that has a single line notice that needs to be updated with user inputted text (via shell script) between two comments acting as tags, for example:

```
<!--BeginNoticeMSG-->NOTICE: This is a notice<!--EndNoticeMSG-->
```

The user inputted text (stored in a variable, let's call it `$NEWNOTICE`) would then need to replace what's between the tags, so effectively:

```
<!--BeginNoticeMSG-->$NEWNOTICE<!--EndNoticeMSG-->
```

Which would get inserted into the `htm` file as (for example):

```
<!--BeginNoticeMSG-->This is a test notice<!--EndNoticeMSG-->
```

How can I identify and replace the text between the tags properly?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1655874

Comment: If you want to do that as an exercise in string manipulation, why not. However I would think that the proper way for this kind of task is to use an `include`, if possible. Apache does allow that: `<!--#include virtual="path/name/noticefile" -->`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a (quite) basic recipe that will meet your need only as exactly specified:

```
#!/bin/bash
REPLACEWITH="Your replacement text here"
STARTTAG="BeginNoticeMSG"
ENDTAG="EndNoticeMSG"
sed -E "s/(<\!\-\-$STARTTAG\-\->)(.*)(<\!\-\-$ENDTAG\-\->)/\1$REPLACEWITH\3/" -i target_file.html
```

It will break in a number of different ways if the input is different, especially if the input "tag" is broken into multiple lines.

Using regular expressions isn't typically recommended to process HTML and XML (I realize this is just a comment), but... If your input is as reliable as hinted by in this post, something this simple may do the trick.

I this case I back-reference the parts of your tag as `\1` and `\3` (which correlate to the parenthetical items in the regex) to reduce the amount of text needed to type out the replacement.

Or without `-E` option, and without back references:

```
#!/bin/bash
REPLACEWITH="Text to replace with here"
STARTTAG="BeginNoticeMSG"
ENDTAG="EndNoticeMSG"
sed -e "s/<\!\-\-$STARTTAG\-\->.*<\!\-\-$ENDTAG\-\->/<\!\-\-$STARTTAG\-\->$REPLACEWITH<\!\-\-$ENDTAG\-\->/" -i target_file.html
```

Comment: Looks like I am using an older version of sed, it does not support the -E option (nor the equivalent -r), taking this option off altogether produces an error:  "sed: command garbled"  Thoughts?

Comment: `sed -e "s/<\!\-\-$STARTTAG\-\->.*<\!\-\-$ENDTAG\-\->/<\!\-\-$STARTTAG\-\->$REPLACEWITH<\!\-\-$ENDTAG\-\->/" -i test.txt` This doesn't require extended regex, and doesn't use the back reference.

Comment: Also edited the answer to add an option without `-E`

Comment: Almost there, this produced:   `<!--BeginNoticeMSG-->This is a test notice<..!--EndNoticeMSG-->`   somehow got a few extra dots in there.

Comment: Interesting! I have sed 4.2.1, see what you have with `sed --version`. Here's a log from my terminal showing it working in test: http://www.pasteall.org/42676/bash

Comment: Well, I thought I could get by here, but I've been outed.  This is sed on SunOS 5.9, not GNU unfortunately, it's the base OS install of sed (which probably explains why I've been struggling with it so much)

Comment: I've got a solaris box around, let me see what happens on it...

Comment: This is a more terse example, but, it did indeed work on SunOS 5.10: http://www.pasteall.org/42677/bash

Comment: Got it working, sloppy copy/paste job on my part and didn't validate.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you never have more than one notice on the same line (more precisely, that you never have more than one occurrence of `<!--BeginNoticeMSG-->` or of `<!--EndNoticeMSG-->` on the same line):

```
sed -e "s&\(<!--BeginNoticeMSG-->\).*\(<!--EndNoticeMSG-->\)&\1$NEWNOTICE\2&"
```

If the begin and end comments can vary, you can write a regular expression for them.

Note that this only works if you are sure that `$NEWNOTICE` does not contain `\`, `&` or newline, because otherwise these characters are interpreted as sed syntax.

To be robust with punctuation characters, use awk instead.

```
export NEWNOTICE
awk '{sub(/<!--BeginNoticeMSG-->.*<!--EndNoticeMSG-->/, "<!--BeginNoticeMSG-->" env[NEWNOTICE] "<!--EndNoticeMSG-->"); print}'
```