# How to use sed with many extra characters in path?

Tags: linux, sed, special-characters

Is it possible to use `sed` to replace the entire example bracketed line below? I seem to be running into trouble finding out a delimiter to use since `/` and many other special characters exist in the actual line I want to replace.

#### Line needing replacing:

*This is a random example since the actual line I want to use is much less friendly to the eyes.*

```
[...]
<example>=(a,b,c);{!@#$%^&*?/};</example>
[...]
```

If there is any tool better suited for this please let me know. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77590/117549

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the *entire* line only, you can use a simple workaround in a similar fashion to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/257913/135943).

Here is your line:

```
<example>=(a,b,c);{!@#$%^&*?/};</example>
```

The workaround is, print this line before the rest of the file, then use Sed to change any lines which entirely consist of an exact match of the first line.

```
{ printf '%s\n' '<example>=(a,b,c);{!@#$%^&*?/};</example>'; cat somefile;} |
  sed -e '1h;1d;G;s/^\(.*\)\n\1$/text to change to/;t' -e 's/\n.*$//'
```

However—you should learn [which characters need escaping in a Sed regex](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32907/135943), anyway.